# Remove carousel sliding in one page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am using bootstrap and I want to use the carousel in one page without sliding.

I've seen this effect can be removed by setting interval to false. The problem is that I want to have a sliding carousel in my home page but not in the rest. So changing this value is not a valid solution for me.

How can I solve this???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that when we add data-interval="false" it stops sliding:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <div class="navigationBarImg">
                <img src="/Images/Pictures/1254_1.jpg" class="image-responsive" alt="First slide">
            </div>
            <div class="container"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="navigationBarImg">
                <img src="/Images/Pictures/1308_1.jpg" class="image-responsive" alt="Second slide">
            </div>
            <div class="container"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="navigationBarImg">
                <img src="/Images/Pictures/1375_1.jpg" class="image-responsive" alt="Third slide">
            </div>
            <div class="container"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
</div><!-- /.carousel -->
```